# What is the best java library to create SCORM manifest xml

Tags: java, xml, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have a Java application that creates educational content (courses, lessons, etc), and want to export this content to SCORM 2004 version 4 standard.

I didn't find any Java jars\projects that can help me to create and validate the scorm manifest.xml.

Do you know a good Java project that can help me in the creation and validation process for the XML?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a [link](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/) some to useful DTDs.

What you need to do is to write validators using some framework. I recommend using DOM. Here's a link to a [XML validator using DTD tutorial](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/DTD-Validation-of-XML-with-DTD-Using-DOM.html)

Comment: Thanks! About those XSDs, do I need to validate my xml against each one of them individually?

Comment: You validate the XML against the applicable schema or DTD. W3Schools have some really simple tutorials on how to do this. I strongly recommend them.

Answer (score 1):

ADL's Reload Content Editor is an open source Java app that helps generate conformant SCORM packages. You might be able to use some of the code in it.

http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-4th/